# Even number of steps for a DTMC to abandon a communication class (first step analysis problem)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

[image]

> Let $\{X_n\}$ be a Markov chain with transition probabilities, as shown in the figure. If $X_0=5$, using first step analysis or whatever method you prefer, evaluate the probability  that in an even number of steps, the chain abandons the communication class it begins from.

*Attempt.* The communication class that contains state $5$ is 
$\{4,5,6\}$, which is open (leading to classes $\{1,2,3\},~\{7,8\}$). For the first step analysis, if $T=\inf\{k\geq 0:~X_k\notin \{4,5,6\}\}$ the first time our chain leaves the above class, we should have:

$$P(T \in 2\mathbb{N}~|~X_0=5)=\sum_{i\in I}P(E_i)~P(T \in 2\mathbb{N}~|~X_0=5,~E_i)$$
for some proper sets $E_i,~i\in I$ that partition the prob. space. I am having difficulty to find these intermediate sets though.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Define set $A = \{4,5,6\}$. What if you define $p_4, p_5, p_6$ as the probability we leave the set $A$ after an even number of jumps, given we start in states $4, 5, 6$ respectively, and define $q_4, q_5, q_6$ as the probability we leave set $A$ in an odd number of jumps.   Can you argue that $p_i+q_i=1$, and then get a set of equations you can eventually solve?

Comment: PS:  The best "$E_i$" events you refer to (assuming we start in state 5) seem to be $$\{\mbox{visit state 4 next}\}, \{\mbox{visit state 6 next}\}, \{\mbox{visit state 7 next}\}$$ which partitions the sample space since there are no other states we can next jump to (given we start in 5).

Comment: @Michael of course $p_i+q_i=1$, since for $X_0=i$, then $T<+\infty$ with prob $1$ (the class is open, leading to the other $2$ classes), so $T$ is even or odd with prob $1$ and we get the desired equality. We actually need to find $p_5$. Which equations do you refer to?

Comment: $p_5=P[\mbox{Leave on even}|\mbox{start from 5}] = P[\mbox{leave on even}|\mbox{visit 4 next from 5}](1/2) + ...$  and use $p_i$, $q_i$ notation. You will not get very far if you say "I only need $p_5$."  This problem is not very different from just cmoputing the expected time to leave set $A$, starting in state 5.  How would you solve that?

Comment: Please confirm if you like that the equations you are reffering to are: $p_5=(1/2)q_4+(1/4)q_6+(1/4)q_7$ and $p_6=(1/2)q_4+(1/2)q_8$ and $p_4=(1/3)q_3+(2/3)q_5$, where $q_i=1-p_i$. Also $p_3=p_7=p_8=1$ (since $T=0$ in these cases).

Comment: Looks good, since, for example, $P[\mbox{leave on even} | \mbox{visit 4 next from 5}]  = q_4$.